# Script Execution - innerHTML, jQuery html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

```
document.body.innerHTML = "<script>alert(11);</script>"

$("body").html("<script>alert(11);</script>")
```

`innerHTML` is not executed.

jQuery `html()` is executed.

Why so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can scripts be inserted with innerHTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml)

Answer (score 2):

Without getting into the theoretical questions of why jQuery chose to do this, the jQuery `html()` behaves differently than the native `innerHTML`. By default, jQuery will find the script tags within the HTML, and load then asynchronously. If this behavior is undesirable, you can use [`$.parseHTML`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) to prevent this from happening by setting the third argument to `false`.

```
$("body").empty().append($.parseHTML("<script>alert(11);</script>", document, false));
```

Note that the script tags will not be added to the DOM using this method.

Conversely, if you wish to achieve the same affect as your jQuery statement in vanilla JS, you can do the following.

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.text = 'alert(11);';
document.body.innerHTML = '';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
var x = document.createElement('script');
var y = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
x.text = "alert(11);"
y.parentNode.insertBefore(x, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using innerHTML will stop the script from executing according to the documentation in simple words without going into details.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.appendChild(document.createTextNode("alert('11')"));
    document.body.appendChild(script);
</script>
```